# File uploads with Progressbar in Django

Tags: django, uploadify

I am looking for an example which does a file upload with a progress bar, in Django.
I have been trying djangp-uploadify for quiet sometime, but have not been able to get it working.
I have been trying something similar to that given in [django+uploadify - don't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821612/djangouploadify-dont-working/2887831) and also in https://github.com/tstone/django-uploadify/wiki

Quick Help would be great

Comment: Django-uploadify worked well for me, but you do run into a multitude of Flash domain-related security problems. And you'll also need to write a chunk of really ugly code to relate the file you are uploading with the user currently logged in, as Flash won't send the cookies to your upload script.

Comment: You have a perfectly good answer, and you got it working. And you didn't accept it. Why?

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/ is a perfect solution for a non-flash solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used swfupload and it worked fine for me.

But there are some gotchas which you should take care of 
The answer in this thread [Code samples for Django + SWFUpload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612734/code-samples-for-django-swfupload/61289) helped me
[Code samples for Django + SWFUpload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612734/code-samples-for-django-swfupload/612898#612898) 
[Code samples for Django + SWFUpload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612734/code-samples-for-django-swfupload/1755067#1755067)

Comment: Ignore. I got the project working. I shall upload the test project at some place and update here